# c# linq search an EntityObject values from an IQueryable list

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

i have a `IQueryable<string>` list and  EntityObject that created by EF from db.It has several properties,one of it is property(name is SubmittedID) holds value like this - "MC535, 3782, 3781" - splitted by comma.

I am trying to find first list values on EntityObject's "SubmittedID" property after parsing values correctly.

I am new to LINQ so i m confused how to do it correctly

For example:

On first list  there are values which are :  "549" , "550"
.On second EntityObject's "SubmittedID" property contains a value : "5491 , 5501"  (i need to skip this row)

On first list there is a  value which is :  "329"
.On second EntityObject's "SubmittedID" property contains a value : "329, 5146"  (i need to get this row)

i tried this but it searches for exact match not contains:

```
     var claimRequestNo = from q in this.ObjectContext.GPA_REQUEST
                          select  q.REQUESTNO;
     var result = this.ObjectContext.GPA_TRANSACTIONS.Where(p => claimRequestNo.Contains(p.SubmittedID.Replace(",", " "))) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

you try to find in the second object where the first object contains value which look like `num1 num2 num3`

instead try to:

```
var result = this.ObjectContext.GPA_TRANSACTIONS.Where(p => claimRequestNo.Any(c=> p.SubmittedID.Split(',').Contains(c)));
```

Now, only if the second list contains at least one from the first list

Comment: Thanks but linq gives error:   {"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String[] Split(Char[])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."} System.Exception {System.NotSupportedException}

Comment: I can able to run linq query.Need to convert  EntityObject and IQueryable list to AsEnumarable or List<> type then split method can run.But it can't find first list's values  on EntitiyObject.I check the data it is exist.